# Uploading files to AWS S3 is taking too much time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to store each input payload received to my Java REST API as a separate file into s3. A parent level folder will be created for storing request payloads per day under the s3 bucket.

Input can range between 1 request to upto one million requests per day. Each payload file is tiny, just around 500 bytes.

Storage structure is as below,

```
s3
|_ bucket 
      |_ parent_folder_1 -> (will contain all requests as separate files received on day 1)
      |_ parent_folder_2 -> (will contain all requests as separate files received on day 2)
```

The code is currently handling it by uploading each file in parallel and letting S3 handle the load. I am surprised to see that the time for each upload is increasing, not in correlation to the file size (which is small) but in correlation to the number of objects I am trying to upload.

Is the upload latency due to increased folder size? Is there any best practice to create sub directories under each parent level folder to increase upload speed based on prefix names?

Comment: Does your process call list on the s3 bucket/prefix? Typically it's only list operations that get slower for this reason.

Comment: It does only putObject call of AmazonS3 class for each request